# Migration issue SSP upgrade 2007 to 2010

Tags: migration, shared-service-provider

In case of SSP migration if we want to totally ignore SSP migration to 2010 service application. We want to create all service app new by not doing any SSP upgrade, is there any major problem in this approach?

Can we totally ignore SSP?

regards

Answer (score 4):

Migration of the SSP is not required.  In many cases I had clients that were not really using the user profiles extensively in 2007 so in those cases we configured a user profile service fresh and did not upgrade the SSP.

The things to think about that could be lost are:

- Custom User Profile Properties that were defined; they would have to be defined again.
- Profile data (Departments, Skills, etc) that were filled out within SharePoint and not synchronized to SharePoint.  Expect that all of the source AD properties would be synchronized into the new profile.
- Users who used the MyLinks feature will have social/link data that is stored in the SSP content database.  If this data is not migrated, this data will be lost.  This feature was deprecated though in favor of the tagging feature so it isn't a huge deal in most cases.